# How to use django api with foreignkey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I try to save foreign key in django restframework serializer.

My goal is to save in database information from iframely.com and this part works good. But I need to also save it in specific category. After add field "Board(my category name field)" I have error:  **null value in column "board_id" violates not-null constraint**

My model:

```
class Embed(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    thumbnail_url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    html = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Kategoria')
```

Form:

```
class SubmitEmbed(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField()
    board = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Board.objects.all())
```

Serializer:

```
class EmbedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    board = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Embed
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
def save_embed(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmitEmbed(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = form.cleaned_data['url']
            r = requests.get('http://iframe.ly/api/oembed?url=' + url + '&key=' + settings.IFRAMELY_KEY)
            json = r.json()
            serializer = EmbedSerializer(data=json, context={'request': request})
            if serializer.is_valid():
                embed = serializer.save()
                return render(request, 'embed/embeds.html', {'embed': embed})
    else:
        form = SubmitEmbed()

    return render(request, 'embed/embedadd.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Are you getting `Board` `instance` in your `request`?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have

```
class EmbedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    board = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)
```

You have set board to `read_only`. DRF will drop this field when this field is provided and DRF validation occurs.

You can remove the entire line and it will work.

Comment: Still have error: null value in column "board_id" violates not-null constraint. I don't know how to assign board list choice in Embed model. In admin work good, but on front end not. I first time try building something with django rest framework.